# How to use a servlet in struts2.3?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2

I am developing a website, in which i created a session (action class) and for expire this session, i used a servlet. i have done 'exclude pattern' in struts.xml. But when i map this servlet to my web.xml, the server is not starting "Starting tomcat v7.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem" - tomcat v7.0 server at localhost failed to start.
thanks in advance.
Note : both jars stuts2core and xwork core are of same version

"struts.xml"

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/Logout" />
```

"web.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="MyApp" version="3.0">
<!--<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>-->
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.Logout</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Logout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<display-name>MyApplication</display-name>
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Andrea...i tried everything which was on your post...but still it's not working

Comment: You have the wrong filter

Comment: You've also a wrong mapping for it